# How to show the save dialog box with IDAPython?

Tags: ida, idapython

I want to some strings to the text-file which is chosen from the save dialog box.
Is there any way to show the save dialog box by IDApython and how to write the script code about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `ida_kernwin.ask_file`, as in:

`self.filename=ida_kernwin.ask_file(1, "*.xml", "Enter name of export xml file:")`